# nUnit isnt executing OneTimeSetup first but executing OneTimeTearDown

Tags: nunit, mstest, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I recently made the switch from MSTest to nUnit to run my selenium test.  With MSTest i was running my test
as assembly initialized.  I read that i could do something similar and removed
and added all the necessary elements to run my test using NUnit but the order of
execution from what i read is not working as i expected or i may not be able to do this.

Version of Nunit = 3.12.0

NUnit3TestAdapter = 3.17.0

Below is example of my code
with cs file having my test cases
and another cs file having my setup fixture like below all are in the same namespace.

The issue i'm having is when I run my test case the attribute OneTimeTearDown is getting executed first
before anything else instead of the OneTimeSetup.

```
      using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;
namespace Automation_Test
{

  [TestFixture]
  public class Custom_Tests
  {
    [Test]
    public void Add()
    { /* ... */ }
  }
}
```

The file that used to contain my assembly initialized

```
using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;
namespace Automation_Test
{

   [SetUpFixture]
  public class AssemblyInitializer
  {
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public static void LoginSystem()
    { /* ... */ }

    [OneTimeTearDown] <---- This method is getting trigger first when i run the test instead of onetimesetup
    public static void AssemblyCleanup()
    { /* ... */ }

  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was placing the Playback settings in OneTimeSetup method

```
 Playback.PlaybackSettings.DelayBetweenActions = 750;
 Playback.PlaybackSettings.ThinkTimeMultiplier = 2;
```

Which i didn't show in question.  This was causing a silent
exception which I didn't see occur which would go and bypass

```
   [OneTimeSetUp]
    public static void LoginSystem()
    { /* ... */ }
```

and go directly to the OnetimeTeardown method

I updated my program and unloaded my project and removed references
and elements related to coded ui and correctly added the three assembly
references

1. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback
2. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility
3. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting

After doing this my program worked as should.

Answer (score 1):

To use a `SetUpFixture` as an assembly initializer, it must in the global namespace, that is, outside of any namespaces you specify.

As your code is set up, the fixture functions to initialize the tests **in the namespace** rather than assembly-wide. That may be OK, provided all your tests are in the same namespace. If you have tests in multiple namespaces depending on this setup, that would be a problem.

Even so, it seems odd that your setup does not run but your teardown does. So try moving the `SetUpFixture` into the global namespace and report on what happens. I'll update this if you turn up some more information.